# How to apply TinyMCE text editor in Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, tinymce

I want to apply a rich text editor in my Struts 2 project. For this I am using TinyMCS in the following manner in my .jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sjr" uri="/struts-jquery-richtext-tags"%>
  <s:url var="remoteurl" action="ajax1" />
  <sjr:tinymce
    id="richtextTinymceAdvancedEditor"
    name="notices.contentBody"
    rows="10"
    cols="80"
    width="800"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    editorLocal="de"
    editorTheme="advanced"
    editorSkin="o2k7"
    toolbarAlign="left"
    toolbarLocation="top"
    plugins="safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template"
    toolbarButtonsRow1="save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect"
    toolbarButtonsRow2="cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor"
    toolbarButtonsRow3="tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen"
    toolbarButtonsRow4="insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage"
    onSaveTopics="submitRichtextForm"
  />
```

But it is showing a simple EditArea, no toolbar in that. I have included all required libraries. What else should I do to show a full rich-text editor?

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably missing a `<sj:head>` tag.

Comment: @Aleksandr......When I tried to apply <sj:head> TAG, It is showing Unknown tag warning, and has no effect.

Comment: @Aleksandr....Now it works..I include 
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
And your suggestion works like charm. Thanks a ton.

Comment: The question for me is not how to apply it but how to read it